# Parse Text File and Add Certain Segments to Database

Tags: delphi

I have a text file containing, exported form a PDF file, "datasets" which I want to parse for inserting into a database. The first few lines are shown below:

```
Property Type: [EVLM1111] VAPOR-LIQUID EQUILIBRIUM IN MIXTURES AND SOLUTIONS
State: Two-component system, single-phase liquid or two-phase liquid-liquid in equilibrium with vapor
Pure component 1, liquid in equilibrium with vapor
Pure component 2, liquid in equilibrium with vapor
Parameters: T/K, Temperature
Variables: x 1 /-, Mole fraction of component 1 in liquid phase
P/Pa, Pressure
Method: Direct measurement of P at variable x 1 and constant T
File Number: LB1186
Components: 1. CH 4 , Methane [74-82-8]
2. C 2 H 6 , Ethane [74-84-0]
T/K = 90.69 T/K = 103.99
x 1 P/10 3 Pa x 1 P/10 3 Pa
0.214420 3.592
0.319440 4.993
      ...
```

For example, I'd like to save the value for `File Number` in a Sources table, etc. I've put together some Delphi XE8 code using arrays of hit-terms and corresponding value-widths, but it is proving to be an enormous task to cover the possibilities.

My question is: Is there database design software or, say, a Delphi XE8 component that can help me with job?

Comment: One of the more common approaches to extracting data out of a blob of text is regular expressions. Have you tried that?

Comment: The best aid to dealing with a situation like this is to have a clear idea of the database structure (tables, columns in them and links between them) needed to model whatever the data represents.  Btw do the text labels which precede the colons indicate that the data which follows is from a single field in the Pdf form?

Comment: You have **a** text file or *many* text files?  It seems the latter.  If yes, are they all in the same general format?  You talk about having a hard time covering *"the possibilities"* - how can we possibly help if you know what those possibilities are and we do not?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic and your problem description is rather vague. For example, try extracting 9th line after colon.